# How to login to Twitter account from an iOS APP in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, twitter, ios7, twitter-oauth, social-framework

I need to login to my twitter from my iOS app. I am able to check if there are any accounts that are set up in the settings in the device. Once it is confirmed that there are no accounts configured in the device, i want to able to login to my twitter account and then add the account to my device. I had a little luck in implementing checking if there are any accounts set up in the device using ACAccountStore. But can someone please help in implementing the later part in iOS7?

Comment: You can redirect the user to Twitter settings from where he can login to his twitter account.

Comment: What if i need to login to twitter from my App?

Comment: I don't think Twitter provides anything for In-App login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SLComposeViewController *sheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler completionBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
  [sheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
};
sheet.completionHandler = completionBlock;
sheet.view.hidden = YES;

[_mainViewController presentViewController:sheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  - (IBAction)tweetTapped:(id)sender {
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Your Tweet Message! :)"];
    if (self.imageString)
    {
        [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.imageString]];
    }

    if (self.urlString)
    {
        [tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]];
    }
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                              message:@"You can't tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
  }
}
```